# [: missing `]' error while comparing variables with floating point numbers in a bash script

Tags: bash, variables, comparison

*temp.txt* is a file with a single line:

1.2034 3.2323 4.3121 5.1223

I have to do the following set of operations multiple times with different values so I have it all in a loop. Given below is the main issue I am facing and would appreciate some help solving.

---

```
v1=$(cut -d" " -f2 temp.txt);

v2=$(cut -d" " -f3 temp.txt);

v3=$(cut -d" " -f4 temp.txt);

v4=$(cut -d" " -f5 temp.txt);


#$v1, $v2, $v3, $v4 contain the above 4 values (1.2034, 3.2323, 4.3121, 5.1223). I have verified that. I want to compare their values, but when I do, I get an error because of incorrect syntax.

if [ "$v1" -gt "$v2" | bc ] && [ "$v3" -gt "$v4" | bc ]; then

    echo Yes

fi
```

---

I get this error:

```
line 6: [: missing `]'

File ] is unavailable.
```

---

Could someone please help me with my syntax? I have tried a few different things already and it didn't work. I have tried different combinations of brackets and spaces and both using *bc* and without *bc*.

Comment: `|` in shell is for creating pipes between commands, e.g. `cat foo | wc -l`. Why are you piping the output of `[ "$v1" -gt "$v2"` to `bc ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to construct a valid `bc` expression and pipe it to `bc`, capture the output, then compare *that* to the expected result.

```
if [[ $(echo "$v1 > $v2" | bc) == 1  &&  $(echo "$v3 > $v4" | bc) == 1 ]]; then
  echo Yes
fi
```

---

If `bash` could do floating-point arithmetic (or if your values were actually integers), you could do the comparisons directly in `bash`:

```
if [[ $v1 -gt $v2 && $v3 -gt $v4 ]]; then echo Yes; fi
```

or

```
if (( v1 > v2 && v3 > v4 )); then echo Yes; fi
```

---

A quicker way to populate your four variables is

```
read x1 v1 v2 v3 v4 x2 < temp.txt
```

(`x1` and `x2` are just variables whose value we don't really care about; the first field and any fields that might occur after the 5th thone.)